# float overflow and position conflict

Tags: css

I have a problem with a float which overflows ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sgw4K/3/)).

#### HTML

```
<div id="father">
    <div id="son">
        gruik
    </div>
    <div id="dog">
        gruikgruik gruik gruik gruikg ruik gruik gruikgr uikgruik gruik gruik gruik
    </div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```css
div { border: solid; }
#father { width: 300px; position: relative; }
#father:after { content: ""; display: block; clear: both; }
#son { width: 100px; float: left; border: solid red; }
#dog { float: left; border: solid blue; position: absolute; left: 105px; }
```

As you can see, `#dog` overflows from `#father`. I tried classical CSS techniques but they just do not work (neither the clearfix method, nor `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto;`).

I think the problem appears because of the use of the position CSS properties but I need it.

Comment: What's your goal? I can't tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: j08691: I don't want #dog to overflow from #father, which means that the blue border shall stay in the black border.

Comment: This question needs to be rephrased.

Comment: @KarlotchaHoa don't forget to mark a correct answer if you're happy with one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: absolute;` is correctly positioning the `#dog` element relative to `#father` (because `#father` has `position: relative;`).

However it is only the `#son` element which is giving `#father` its height. Elements positioned absolutely are taken out of the flow and therefore if `#dog` increases in height, its parent container (`#father`) will not, and therefore `#dog` looks to be overflowing.

Why do you have to use `position: absolute;` on `#dog`?

**Can you not just use float, and set its width?** You are setting its parent and siblings widths anyway so you know what width it should be (if you specify the width of the borders too).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sgw4K/5/

**EDIT/UPDATE:** After discovering additional styling, **thirtydot** has recommended two sound fixes to the problem. See comment below or the following:

> To fix that, you can remove `float: left` from `#son` and then pick one of
>   these two choices: `margin-left: 52px` or `overflow: hidden;` on the `#son` element.

Comment: Thank you Dave Haigh, you understood well the problem. However, I can't just use float and set its width. In fact it is my fault (I am sorry), I just write this jsfiddle to reproduce my problem, but in my real situation, father doesn't have a fixed width, I use width: 50%; (which gives: http://jsfiddle.net/sgw4K/28/ )

Comment: You need to rephrase/edit your question and also your jsfiddle in order to give a true representation of what styles you already have. That way it will be easier to determine if you can achieve what you want to achieve. In essence you cannot use `position: absolute;` if you want the content of that element to push the boundaries of its parent i.e. increase its height and not overflow it.

Comment: @KarlotchaHoa: To fix that, you can remove `float: left` from `#son` and then pick one of these two choices: [`margin-left: 52px` (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/sgw4K/29/) or [`overflow: hidden` (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/sgw4K/30/).

Comment: @KarlotchaHoa both of thirtydot's alterations to the jsfiddle will work. I was about to implement the `margin-left` version but he beat me to it.

Comment: The benefit of the `overflow: hidden` solution is that it does not matter what the width of `#dog` is. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/sgw4K/31/

Comment: Thank you very much thirtydot ! And I am sorry for the others if I was not clear, I'll try to be clearer the next time :) 
I tried to use position: relative/absolute because I had just used this little trick: http://bit.ly/urchqV but the solution of thirtydot is perfect. I really like the solution with overflow: hidden, even if I don't really understand it :x
Thanks guys ! :)